# Using AWS CLI, how to query all instances whose ID does not match a list of IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to know if it's possible using AWS Cli tools to query all the instances that do not match a list of IDs.

We are using a tool to create/update/delete instances and this tool has its own database to list existing instances. But before this tool, all were made by hand.

Actually, with have a lot of dummy instances that are not currently used and that we want to delete.

We have the list of used instances and we want to delete all the others. As we have like 500 instances used and 2500 not used, it's a bit painful to do it by hand.

So I would like to query IDs of instances that do not match instances currently in use.

Thanks

Comment: How is that list of IDs currently stored?

Comment: You could use something like `aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?InstanceId!=\`i-78b7e6f3e455238dc\` && InstanceId!=\`i-78b7e6f3e455238db\`]'` but obviously adapted for N instances

Comment: In a single awscli command, no. Write a shell script or Python script using boto3 to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you could do something like this:

```bash
INSTANCE_IDS_BLACKLIST=("i-78b7e6f3e455238dc" "i-78b7e6f3e455238db")
FILTER=$(printf InstanceId!=\`"%s\`\n && " "${INSTANCE_IDS_BLACKLIST[@]}" | head -n -1 | tr -d "\n")
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[?${FILTER}]"
```

This will return any instances whose id does not match any of those present in the `INSTANCE_IDS_BLACKLIST` array.